# How to spawn huge numbers of sprites in minimal lines of code

Tags: c++, stack

Hey so I was working on my pong game and found it quite tedious to design a new sprite ball everytime i wanted to spawn one ase i ended up being very repetative:

```
sf::Image img;
    img.Create(30,50,sf::Color(255,0,0));
    mySprite box(img, sf::Vector2f(0,300), sf::Vector2f(1,1), 0, 36, 300); //TODO: make collision work at extremely high speeds
    box.SetCenter(15,25);

    sf::Image img2;
    img2.Create(56.5,80,sf::Color(255,0,0));
    mySprite box2(img2, sf::Vector2f(800,300), sf::Vector2f(1,1), 0, 239, 300);
    box2.SetCenter(25,40);

    sf::Image img3;
    img3.Create(56.5,80,sf::Color(255,0,10));
    mySprite box3(img3, sf::Vector2f(500,300), sf::Vector2f(1,1), 0, 135, 400);
    box3.SetCenter(25,40);

    sf::Image img4;
    img4.Create(56.5,80,sf::Color(255,166,90));
    mySprite box4(img4, sf::Vector2f(300,500), sf::Vector2f(1,1), 0, 10, 100);
    box4.SetCenter(25,40);
```

Creating a Spawn() function doesn't work because i have to create a new name for the sprite instantiation every new sprite(thus the box,box1,box2, etc.). How can i make a function that somehow randomly formulates a name for another ball i want to spawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't randomly generate variable names. How would you reference them in your code?

Why don't you just use a `vector` to store your images and boxes, and then use a loop to spawn sprites:

```
std::vector<mySprite> boxes;

std::vector<Parameters> parameters;

for(std::vector<Parameters>::iterator it = parameters.begin(); 
    it != parameters.end(); ++it) {
    sf::Image img;
    img.Create(it->param1, it->param2, it->color);
    mySprite box(img, it->vector1, it->vector2, it->param3, it->param4, 
                 it->param5);
    box.SetCenter(it->center);
    boxes.push_back(box);
}
```

This assumes that you have a data-structure `Parameters` that can hold all the parameters you require (with better names than the ones in my example). You then loop over all the parameters-sets you have, and create sprite for each one.

Comment: I don't know the library... was digging around for API docs to see if something like that was safe, the main issue being that `img` is local to the `for` loop in your version, so destroyed after each iteration. Can you confirm that `box()` copies it, rather than say storing a `const` reference to it?  Of course, you could have a `vector` of `Image`s too, but it may not be necessary....

Comment: @Tony: I don't know that either, but it would be trivial to add an extra vector to hold the images, or to modify his class to take a `shared_ptr` to an image.

Comment: yes - plenty of ways around it - mainly mentioning it so if it's cut-and-pasted, but has mysterious crashes, Griffin knows that might be the issue and might save some time....

Comment: So there's no way to avoid allocating huge amounts of memory if i wanted thousands of sprites? That's kinda what i want to avoid... and retyping all this hundreds of times

Comment: If you want hundreds of sprites, you need the memory for them. As for the retyping, the above can be used to create any number of sprites your memory can hold, as long as you can get the parameters into the parameter-vector. I guess you would have those stored in a file, or they are generated at run-time, based on user-input.